# Postfix rejects sender address

Tags: email, postfix

On my LAN are two servers: mail.example.com and alpha.example.com. A script on alpha.example.com sends an email to joe@example.com. Sendmail MTA on alpha.example.com sends this email to mail.example.com. with a "from" address of root@alpha.example.com

Postfix on mail.example.com is rejecting this, the mail log says "**Sender address rejected: Domain not found**"

```
Sep 29 13:58:20 mail postfix/smtpd[22938]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[1.2.3.4]: 450 4.1.8 <root@alpha.example.com>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found; from=<root@alpha.example.com> to=<joe@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<alpha.example.com>
```

I don't understand why mail.example.com can't find domain alpha.example.com. The /etc/hosts on mail.example.com has an entry

```
1.2.3.4   alpha alpha.example.com
```

and I can ping either of those names from mail.example.com

Here's the Postfix main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix

mydestination = mail.localdomain, mail.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost, /etc/postfix/mydomains

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

recipient_delimiter = +

home_mailbox = Mail/
mailbox_size_limit = 0

disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks
 reject_unauth_destination
 reject_unauth_pipelining
 reject_invalid_hostname
 reject_non_fqdn_sender
 reject_unknown_sender_domain
 reject_non_fqdn_recipient
 reject_unknown_recipient_domain
 reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org
 reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net
 reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
 permit

smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${queue_directory}/smtp_scache

myhostname = bubba.localdomain
myorigin = /etc/mailname
relayhost = mail.<my ISP>.com
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_sasl_security_options = noplaintext, noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
```

I have briefly reviewed similar questions on serverfault.com but in my main.cf I don't see a section for smtp_sender_restrictions so I am unclear how to get Postfix to cease rejecting mail from root@alpha.example.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding alpha.example.com to /etc/postfix/mydomains fixed the problem.

On a LAN with dozens or hundreds of servers this would be annoying to maintain, perhaps there's a more general solution?